# What does the garbage collector do if only one instance variable of an object is reachable

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My question is what the comment says in this code snippet:

```java
public class A {
    int x = 0;
}

public class B {
    String text = "a";
    A a = new A();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = null;
        if (a == null) {
            B b = new B();
            a = b.a;
        }
        // what happens with b inside the if statement now?
        // does a still point to b's instance variable?
        // what does the garbage collector do in this case?
    }
}
```

Because the class B holds another instance variable called `text` I was wondering what the garbage collector would do in this case. If `b` inside of the if statement would not get garbage collected and `a` still points to the instance variable `a` of `b`, wouldn't `text` waste memory space then?

EDIT:

`a` inside of the main function is used later somehow and is not unreachable!

The interesting part is what happens with `b`, because `a` inside `B` is still being referenced but `text` not.

Comment: Depends on the GC implementation. As `b` is never used again and that variable holds the only reference to the `B` instance, the instance is at least _conceptually_ eligible for garbage collection. Whether or not a GC implementation will be that fine-grained is, well, implementation dependent. You also have to consider changes made by JIT while the code is running, which may affect how things are seen by the GC.

Comment: Also `"a"` is a string literal and also interned. I'm not sure it will be GC'd even when the `B` instance is GC'd.

Comment: _inside_ `if` statement, `b` is reachable, since you are using it, it simply can't be GC-ed. Immediately after the `if` statement, everything is eligible for GC - since you do not use it, as such it is un-reachable.

Comment: @Slaw `JIT`, in this case, will only make things far more aggressive, since these are pure local objects, they might not be allocated at all.

Comment: There is nothing interesting in the `B` instance. When it became unreachable, it will be unreachable. The contents of an unreachable object is irrelevant.

Comment: @Holger I am a beginner in this topic and that was my question. I assumed that if `a` still points to to `a` inside `b` and therefore `b` could not be garbage collected because it is still reachable. This was interesting for me because in this case `text` would be hold without a need for that to happen. That's why I asked this question - to get to know how this is internally handled.

Comment: The local variable `a` within the `main` method *does not* point to the `a` field in the `B` instance. These are two entirely unrelated variables which happen to point to the same object, an instance of `A`. Just because two variables have the same value, they do not point to each other. This is not handled internally, because there is nothing to handle. Say, I have a key to your house. How does it affect your briefcase containing the other key? Does my key prevent you from dropping your briefcase from a bridge?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = null;
    if (a == null) {
        B b = new B();
        a = b.a;
    }
    // let's suppose GC is called here
}
```

Both `a` and `b` instances are not used after the `if` statement - they can and will be reclaimed if the GC runs, both of them. You can read "un-used" as "un-reachable". It is as simple as that.

On the other hand, if you change it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = null;
    if (a == null) {
        B b = new B();
        a = b.a;
    }
    // GC called here
    // somehow use "a"
}
```

If you make `a` reachable, it can not be reclaimed, only `b` can, since, well - no one needs it.